# stat millions of files in fastest time possible

Tags: python, performance, file-io, comparison, stat

so i would like to do some "big data" analysis of some science data files. more specifically, i would like to gather the atime, mtime and ctimes of these files to determine appropriate hierarchical storage management policies, and thus effective planning for storage tiers.

constraints are:

- we have many solaris systems (zfs), and some linux
- we have literally a billion+ files
- we have probably ~100 storage servers

i have ansible all set up to 'embarrassingly parallelize' the data collection.

i investigated using the `find` command, but the solaris version is rather limited (no `-print`). so i decided to write a python script to gather the data. it looks something like this:

```
def os_path_get( filename ):
  return {
    'atime': os.path.getatime( filename ),
    'mtime': os.path.getmtime( filename ),
    'ctime': os.path.getctime( filename ),
    'size': os.path.getsize( filename )
  }

def stat_get( filename ):
  (mode, ino, dev, nlink, uid, gid, size, atime, mtime, ctime) = os.lstat( filename )
  return {
    'atime': atime,
    'mtime': mtime,
    'ctime': ctime,
    'size': size,
    'inode': ino,
  }

for root, directory, filenames in os.walk(this):
  for filename in filenames:
    path = os.path.join(root,filename)
    if not os.path.islink( path ):
      # d = os_path_get( path )
      d = stat_get( path )
      print "%s\t%s\t%s\t%s" % ( d['size'], d['ctime'], d['mtime'], d['atime'] )
```

(i would likely either dump the `now()` time, or work the diff calculation in the output)

however, on one test server, with ~52 million files, it took about 70 hours to run with `os_path_get()`.

my non-scientific tests of using `stat_get()` over `os_path_get()` is that the latter is perhaps about 50% slower.

any suggestions on how to improve the speed of this meta data collection? ( multiple threads... `os.scandir()`...?)